# How to add unrepeated row of second csv to the end on first one and merge to new csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv file like `test1.csv`, `test2.csv` and in them some column headers aren't repeated and I need to append second unrepeated column to end of first and merge it to `'merge.csv'` when my program appends it to first. Here is my code :

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', quotechar = '"') for f in all_filenames])
combined_csv.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI')
```

First csv `data1.csv` is like :

```
id;name;surname
23764;olzhas;bermaganbetov
23001;zhanik;kalieva
```

Second one `data2.csv` is like :

```
id;name;country
23732;almas;almaty
23001;aierke;astana
```

Here is the result: `merged.csv`

```
country;id;name;surname
;23764;olzhas;bermaganbetov
;23001;zhanik;kalieva
almaty;23732;almas;
astana;23001;aierke;
```

when I need something like:

```
id;name;surname;country
23764;olzhas;bermaganbetov;
23001;zhanik;kalieva;
23732;almas;almaty
23001;aierke;astana
```

Comment: this `23001;aierke;astana` should be like `23001;aierke;;astana`, in your expected output?

Comment: use `combined_csv = combined_csv[['id','name','surname','country']]` after your `pd.concat`